# Error uploading file to firebase from ios only

Tags: dart, flutter

I am getting the following error when trying to upload an image to firebase storage:

`PlatformException(Error -13000, FIRStorageErrorDomain, An unknown error occurred, please check the server response.)`

Its strange as i dont get this error when calling the exact same function from an android device. When i call the function:

```
Future saveToStorage(File image) async {
  FirebaseStorage.instance.setMaxOperationRetryTimeMillis(10);
  storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("AllUsers").child(uuid).child(imageFileName);

  final StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(image, const StorageMetadata(contentLanguage: "en"));
  await uploadTask.future.then( (UploadTaskSnapshot snapshot) { // hangs at this line
    if (snapshot.downloadUrl != null) {
      String downloadUrl = snapshot.downloadUrl.toString();
      final fireImage = new FireImage(imageFileName, currentDateTime, imageCount, downloadUrl);
      storage.deleteImageFile(imageFileName);
      saveToDatabase(fireImage);
      instance.setInt("ImageCount", imageCount + 1);
    } else {
      saveFile(image);
    }
  })
}
```

The code hangs at the point `await uploadTask.future.then( etc` then gives the above error.

Update 1:
Ive just noticed this error too `[Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error`

Update 2:
This error is now appearing:

```
  [] __nwlog_err_simulate_crash_libsystem libsystem simulate crash unavailable "libsystem_network.dylib: nw_host_stats_add_src :: received error for SRC_ADDED: [22] Invalid argument"
  [] nw_host_stats_add_src received error for SRC_ADDED: [22] Invalid argument, dumping backtrace:
  [x86_64] libnetcore-856.1.8
  0   libsystem_network.dylib             0x0000000115e4480e __nw_create_backtrace_string + 123
  1   libsystem_network.dylib             0x0000000115e5b358 nw_get_host_stats + 1083
  2   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000011712aca9 nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child + 1382
  3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000115bcc810 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
  4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000115bee12e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
  5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000115bd3523 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 1018
  6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000115bd3cf3 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1118
  7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000115bd5a0e _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 506
  8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000115bd57b4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 113
  9   libsystem_pthrea
```

Can anyone see why im getting this error only on ios?

Answer (score 0):

The way ive worked around this is by calling `final url = (await uploadTask.future).downloadUrl;` and checking if downloadUrl is not null, the call is being made this way. If you can see other work arounds that would be great.

```
Future saveToStorage(File image) async {
  FirebaseStorage.instance.setMaxUploadRetryTimeMillis(100)
  final StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("AllUsers").child(uuid).child(imageFileName);
  final StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(image, const StorageMetadata(contentLanguage: "en"));
  print("Saving to storage here with file: $image");
  final url = (await uploadTask.future).downloadUrl;
    print("uploading image: $image");
    if (url != null) {
      print("got here with url");
      String downloadUrl = url.toString();
      final fireImage = new FireImage(imageFileName, currentDateTime, imageCount, downloadUrl);
      storage.deleteImageFile(imageFileName);
      print('download URL: $downloadUrl');
      saveToDatabase(fireImage);
      instance.setInt("ImageCount", imageCount + 1);
    } else {
      print("got here without url");
      saveFile(image);
    }
}
```